# Shared WebClient, PUT/POST request fails only after GET request

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, webclient

Recently I discovered that it is recommended to re-use a `WebClient` instead of initializing multiple instances. The `PUT` request works fine unless I initiate a `GET` request prior to the `PUT` on the same `WebClient`. When calling a `PUT` request following a `GET` than I receive `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

```
private readonly WebClient _wc;

public API(string apiKey, string apiPassword, string hostName)
{
    _apiKey = apiKey;
    _apiPassword = apiPassword;
    _hostName = hostName;

    _wc = new WebClient();
    _wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    _wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_apiKey, _apiPassword);
}


...

// Standard Get Request working fine
_wc.DownloadString(url);

// If we comment out the next line (which re-initializes the Webclient), the PUT request will fail.
_api = new API(username, password, hostName);

// PUT Request only works if the WebClient is re-initialized.
_wc.UploadString(url, "PUT", json);
```

It doesn't seem to be a threshold issue as I tried putting a drastic delay between the two requests. Should `PUT`, `GET`, and `POST` all have a seperate `WebClient`, or is there some type of flushing I need to do between requests?

EDIT: I receive the same symptoms with a `POST` following a `GET` request - not `PUT` specific.

Comment: Is this on a server? If yes, did you try removing webdav ? Though I doubt it will fix the problem given how you described it

Comment: @Qudus This is the client portion, which communicates with the [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference).